# How to correctly get a data by using async operations?

Tags: c#, multithreading

I need to handle concurrent request by waiting the result of an already running operation.

```
private readonly object _gettingDataTaskLock = new object();
private Task<Data> _gettingDataTask;

public virtual Data GetData(Credential credential)
{
    Task<Data> inProgressDataTask = null;

    lock (_gettingDataTaskLock)
    {
        if (_gettingDataTask == null)
        {
            _gettingDataTask = Task.Factory.StartNew(() 
                                                    => GetDataInternal(credential));
            _gettingDataTask.ContinueWith((task) =>
            {
                lock (_gettingDataTaskLock)
                {
                    _gettingDataTask = null;
                }
             },
             TaskContinuationOptions.ExecuteSynchronously);
         }

          inProgressDataTask = _gettingDataTask;
     }

     try
     {
         return inProgressDataTask.Result;
     }
     catch (AggregateException ex)
     {
         _logger.ErrorException(ex, "An error occurs during getting full data");
         throw ex.InnerException;
      }
 }
```

I have a potential problem: a couple of calls `GetData` might be with different `credentials`. First call with the right credential and then a couple with wrong credentials. And this couple requests got the same answer as the first one. How to fix that problem?

Is there any way to simplify this code and do it thread safe and bug free?

Comment: Does this code work ? It seems dead locked.

Comment: @MikeMazmanyan Yes, it work

Comment: Which .NET framework version are you using?

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov 4.5.2

Comment: Is there a reason `inProgressDataTask` is a global variable?

Comment: Yes, its ok, I'm using it in constructor

Comment: What are you actually trying to achieve? Your code doesn't really seems to make too much sense.

Comment: So... you're launching a task on a new thread, so that you could synchronously wait for the same task just a few lines later. I'd say it contains the worst kind of bug - "This shouldn't have ever been written in the first place". Perhaps you'd like to replace the whole thing with `try { return GetDataInternal(); } catch { _logger.ErrorException(ex, "An error occurs during getting full data"); throw; }`?

Comment: Can you explain please this bug a little bit deeper?

Comment: I need to handle concurrent request by waiting the result of an already running operation.

Comment: @Anatoly, so would you prefer `async` code or blocking code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's my interpretation of the requirements:

- Requests for data may come in simultaneously with same/different credentials.
- For each unique set of credentials there can be at most one `GetDataInternal` call in progress, with the result from that one call returned to all queued waiters when it is ready.
- After this the results of the previous call are invalidated, and a new `GetDataInternal` call will be allowed with the same set of credentials.
- Parallel calls to `GetDataInternal` with different credentials are allowed.

Easy peasy.

```
private readonly Dictionary<Credential, Lazy<Data>> Cache
    = new Dictionary<Credential, Lazy<Data>>();

public Data GetData(Credential credential)
{
    if (credential == null)
    {
        // Pass-through, no caching.
        return GetDataInternal(null);
    }

    Lazy<Data> lazy;

    lock (Cache)
    {
        if (!Cache.TryGetValue(credential, out lazy))
        {
            // ExecutionAndPublication is the default LazyThreadSafetyMode, but I 
            // wanted to spell it out to drive the point home: this Lazy instance 
            // will only allow a single call to GetDataInternal, even if multiple
            // threads query its Value property simultaneously.
            lazy = new Lazy<Data>(
                () => GetDataInternal(credential),
                LazyThreadSafetyMode.ExecutionAndPublication
            );

            Cache.Add(credential, lazy);
        }
    }

    // We have released the lock on Cache to allow other threads
    // (with potentially *different* credentials) to access the
    // cache and proceed with their own work in parallel with us.
    Data data;

    try
    {
        // Wait for the GetDataInternal call to complete.
        data = lazy.Value;
    }
    finally
    {
        // At this point the call to GetDataInternal has completed and Data is ready.
        // We will invalidate the cache entry if another thread hasn't done so already.
        lock (Cache)
        {
            // The lock is required to ensure the atomicity of our "fetch + compare + remove" operation.
            // *ANY* thread is allowed to invalidate the cached value, not just the thread that created it.
            // This ensures that the cache entry is cleaned up sooner rather than later.
            // The equality check on the Lazy<Data> instance ensures that the cache entry
            // is not cleaned up too soon, and prevents the following race:
            // (assume all operations use identical credentials)
            // - Thread A creates and stores a Lazy<Data> instance in the cache.
            // - Thread B fetches the Lazy<Data> instance created by Thread A.
            // - Threads A and B access Lazy<Data>.Value simultaneously.
            // - Thread B wins the race and enters the second (this) protected
            //   region and invalidates the cache entry created by Thread A.
            // - Thread C creates and stores a *NEW* Lazy<Data> instance in the cache.
            // - Thread C accesses its Lazy<Data>.Value.
            // - Thread A finally gets to invalidate the cache, and OOPS, Thread C's cache
            //   entry is invalidated before the call to Lazy<Data>.Value has completed.
            // With the equality check in place, Thread A will *not*
            // invalidate the cache entry created by another thread.
            Lazy<Data> currentLazy;

            if (Cache.TryGetValue(credential, out currentLazy) && lazy == currentLazy)
            {
                // Need to invalidate.
                Cache.Remove(credential);
            }
        }
    }

    return data;
}
```

Things to note:

- Credential must override `Equals` and `GetHashCode` for the purpose of equality comparison.
- Be *very* careful overriding this method if you choose to make it virtual.
- Error handling was removed to focus on the "meat".

The above converts to a `Task<Data>`-returning method with a few small tweaks if you're on .NET 4.5 or above (or a few large nasty changes if you're on .NET 4.0). Let me know if it's a requirement and, if so, which version of .NET you're targeting.

**EDIT**: I have added a `try/finally` - should have been there to begin with.

Also, here's a `ConcurrentDictionary` version where I worked around its limitations - you will notice that it is only a bit cleaner:

```
private readonly ConcurrentDictionary<Credential, Lazy<Data>> Cache
    = new ConcurrentDictionary<Credential, Lazy<Data>>();

public Data GetData(Credential credential)
{
    if (credential == null)
    {
        // Pass-through, no caching.
        return GetDataInternal(null);
    }

    // This instance will be thrown away if a cached
    // value with our "credential" key already exists.
    Lazy<Data> newLazy = new Lazy<Data>(
        () => GetDataInternal(credential),
        LazyThreadSafetyMode.ExecutionAndPublication
    );

    Lazy<Data> lazy = Cache.GetOrAdd(credential, newLazy);
    bool added = ReferenceEquals(newLazy, lazy); // If true, we won the race.
    Data data;

    try
    {
        // Wait for the GetDataInternal call to complete.
        data = lazy.Value;
    }
    finally
    {
        // Only the thread which created the cache value
        // is allowed to remove it, to prevent races.
        if (added) {
            Cache.TryRemove(credential, out lazy);
        }
    }

    return data;
}
```

Comment: What do you think about using ConcurrentDictionary?

Comment: Can you explain please why do we need second `lock` ? I cannot understand this part of code (started from second `lock`)

Comment: `ConcurrentDictionary` provides a solid set of atomic operations, however check + remove (used in the second half of the method which I will explain in a bit) is not one of them. When you start combining separate lookup and data manipulation operations, thread safety goes out the window regardless of whether the collection is thread safe, hence I opted not to use `ConcurrentDictionary\`2`.

Comment: Thank you very much. Waiting for your update about the second part of the code

Comment: I have added a `ConcurrentDictionary` version also for your reference (had to get a bit creative with it to ensure an atomic "check if value exists + store value if necessary + return true if we succeeded at storing the value")

Comment: What do you mean by `TryAdd`  in the `If TryAdd does not succeed`? You dont have a method with this name

Comment: Apologies: I really meant "if we do not succeed at storing the value". `TryAdd` only provides 2 out of 3 things we need at that point: it does not fetch the current value if storing the new value does not succeed, so I could not use it.

Comment: Can you please explain or comment your code with some example with two or more threads?

Comment: @Anatoly, I am afraid I don't have the brainpower to do a full write-up as it's close to 3am where I am (and it's no longer fun anyway), but I've added a few comments which will clear things up in parts of code others are likely to find the most confusing.

Comment: Any specific reason you used `lazy == currentLazy` in the first version and `ReferenceEquals(newLazy, lazy)` in the second? (And for what its worth for 3 AM I thought your comments were very good and informative)

Comment: @ScottChamberlain I think as @Kirill said we need to use `ReferenceEquals(newLazy, lazy)` to update our dictionary.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain Can you re-write a code without using `ReferenceEquals` ?

Comment: @ScottChamberlain You think we can just return `newLazy.Value`?

Comment: @Anatoly you can't, you would brake it, everything there is needed.

Comment: I don't understand the first comment. Why we will be thrown away if a cached value with our "credential" key already exists?

Comment: @ScottChamberlain, regarding the eq comparison, the only reason was code style. I simply don't like the look of `bool added = (newLazy == lazy)`, which is why I opted for `ReferenceEquals`. Otherwise they are identical as the eq operator is not overridden by `Lazy<T>`, and `ReferenceEquals(object objA, object objB)` simply returns `objA == objB`.

Comment: @Anatoly, as I mentioned in my first comment, `ReferenceEquals` and `==` are interchangeable (in the case of `Lazy<T>`), so you can pick whatever you feel is more readable. As for "throwing away `newLazy` if a cached value already exists", I made that comment because `newLazy` is *always* allocated, and if `GetOrAdd` returns an already existing `Lazy<Data>` instance, `newLazy` simply gets garbage collected. That feels untidy, but I couldn't think of a way of ensuring thread safety using the `ConcurrentDictionary` API without paying for that (potentially unnecessary) allocation.

Comment: @Anatoly, re 16:33:00Z comment: you shouldn't return (or touch in any other way) `newLazy.Value` as that would result in `GetDataInternal` being called on every `GetData` call, rendering the caching useless. That's obviously not what you want.

Comment: @Anatoly, following your comment questioning why we need the second lock, I have re-read your question carefully and realised I made a mistake with one of my assumptions: you have not requested the value to be invalidated immediately after being created - instead you are storing it for future requests to reuse. If you really think this is the behaviour you want (I don't think caching an auth result indefinitely is a good idea, but it's your call), you could, indeed, replace my entire `try/finally` with `return lazy.Value`.

Comment: @KirillShlenskiy Thanks, also I don't want to have `ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null` inside `GetorAdd` when `credentials == null`? What the correct way to handle this situation?

Comment: @Anatoly, is `null` a valid value for `credentials`? I'd throw a `NullReferenceException` if it's not, and possibly introduce a direct call to `GetDataInternal` if it is.

Comment: @KirillShlenskiy If I have `credentials == null` one part of my data will be setted, just some property in `Data`. And if `credentials != null` all of `Data` will be setted.

Comment: @KirillShlenskiy Do you mean add  `if (credentials == null) {return newLazy.Value; }` ?

Comment: @KirillShlenskiy How to be without remove from the cache? If I have some request with `credential-> data`, and after 10 minutes my data on the disk will be changed, so I initiate another request to collect new data, but with the same credential. If I dont do remove I get same old data. Am I right?

Comment: @Anatoly, I've added pass-through `GetDataInternal` calls as `null` credentials can't be cached. Regarding not removing data from the cache: you are correct in saying that persisting data in the cache indefinitely is harmful if your `Data` goes stale after a period of time. If you don't invalidate the cache *at some point*, you will keep getting the same data. The main question here is - when is it the right time to invalidate.

Comment: Personally I believe that the best solutions in your case are either deterministic invalidation (where the cache is invalidated at the same time `Data` itself is changed), or a reasonable time-based invalidation policy where cache entries are auto-invalidated after a certain well-defined period of time. Both, however, are complex and outside the scope of this question. You are welcome to consider your options, try to clarify your requirements, have a stab at implementing, and come back with specific issues you encounter as your design evolves (try to break them down into smaller new questions)

Comment: @KirillShlenskiy Thank you very much!

Comment: @KirillShlenskiy I have added new updated question. Please, look when you have a time http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34285365/how-to-use-memorycache-insted-of-timer-to-trigger-a-method

Answer (score 3):

Updated:

It seems like here is implemented double lock checking like in singleton pattern. `GetDataInternal()` is cached as long as it executes.
For example if it executes in 100ms and you run one `GetData()` per 10ms, first 10 calls will use the same `GetDataInternal()`.

TaskContinuationOptions.ExecuteSynchronously is used to ensure that continuation is run in the same thread.

```
 public virtual Data GetData(Credential credential)
 {
     Task<Data> inProgressDataTask = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => GetDataInternal(credential));

     try
     {
         return inProgressDataTask.Result;
     }
     catch (AggregateException ex)
     {
         _logger.ErrorException(ex, "An error occurs during getting full data");
         throw ex.InnerException;
     }
 }
```

async/await scenario:

Change `Data GetInternalData()` to `async Task<Data> GetInternalData()`

Change method `GetData()` to

```
public virtual async Task<Data> GetData()
{
     try
     {
         return await GetInternalData();
     }
     catch (AggregateException ex)
     {
         _logger.ErrorException(ex, "An error occurs during getting full data");
         throw ex.InnerException;
     }
 }
```

Comment: I don't think so. The continuation is going to (try to) execute synchronously with respect to the `_gettingDataTask` - it has nothing to do with the "outside lock".

Comment: The thing is that they are locking the same object. And the inside lock should wait for outside to release the lock

Comment: Well, not really. First, the outside doesn't wait for the inner task to complete, so at worst, they would be serialized (note that the wait is *after* the outer lock is released). Second, if it actually *did* execute synchronously, the `lock` wouldn't matter either, since `lock`s are reentrant.

Comment: I need to handle concurrent request by waiting the result of an already running operation.

Comment: @Anatoly it depends what kind of task is doing `GetDataInternal()`. Does it need to be cached?

Comment: @MikeMazmanyan Yes, I need the result of an already running operation.

Comment: @Anatoly are you familiar with async/await pattern introduced in C# 5.0 ? Does `GetInternalData()` return the same data every time you call it ?

Comment: @MikeMazmanyan What do you think about another answer from @Kirill?

Comment: @Anatoly it's up to you to decide whether you need caching or not, but if GetInternalData is thread safe then you can just remove everything and leave only it's call.

Comment: @MikeMazmanyan `GetDataInternal` just do all things inside one big `lock`. Is it thread safe?

Comment: @MikeMazmanyan I cannot understand how do you handle the situation that I describe like potential problem in my question?

Answer (score 0):

When you use `Multithreading` or `Multiprocessing`, you must do something to manage them. `Multithreading` is a vast and complex topic. Different scenarios may occur with your code; Suppose that before running this line of code:

```
return inProgressDataTask.Result;
```

Each thread execute this line of code:

```
_gettingDataTask = null;
```

This is possible because the `Task`s was run in `async`.
Note that the `inProgressDataTask` refers to the place that `_gettingDataTask`  refers:

```
inProgressDataTask = _gettingDataTask;
```

`_gettingDataTask` Object is shared between all tasks (threads), and this may cause errors in the program. If you want to use it In this case, you can use somthing like [Singleton](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650316.aspx) pattern. Don't use the `Task.Factory.StartNew` or `_gettingDataTask.ContinueWith` (that runs in async) in lock section of your code, if you use the shared objects.

Or suppose that before run this line of code:

```
_gettingDataTask = null;
```

Some of the other threads execute this line of code:

```
if (_gettingDataTask == null)
```

That makes all the answers related to the first thread is executed.

To clarify the issue creeate new project and add following code into it:

```
class Test
{
    private readonly object _gettingDataTaskLock = new object();
    private Task<int> _gettingDataTask;

    public int GetData(int credential)
    {
        Task<int> inProgressDataTask = null;
        Console.WriteLine(credential + "-TEST0");
        lock (_gettingDataTaskLock)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(credential + "-TEST1");
            if (_gettingDataTask == null)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(credential + "-TEST2");
                _gettingDataTask = Task.Factory.StartNew(()
                    => GetDataInternal(credential));
                _gettingDataTask.ContinueWith((task) =>
                {
                    lock (_gettingDataTaskLock)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(credential + "-TEST3");
                        _gettingDataTask = null;
                        Console.WriteLine(credential + "-TEST4");
                    }
                },
                    TaskContinuationOptions.ExecuteSynchronously);
                Console.WriteLine(credential + "-TEST5");
            }

            //_gettingDataTask.Wait();
            Console.WriteLine(credential + "-TEST6");
            inProgressDataTask = _gettingDataTask;
            Console.WriteLine(credential + "-TEST7");
        }
        Console.WriteLine(credential + "-TEST8");
        try
        {
            Console.WriteLine(credential + "-TEST9");
            return inProgressDataTask.Result;
        }
        catch (AggregateException ex)
        {
            throw ex.InnerException;
        }
    }

    private int GetDataInternal(int credential)
    {
        return credential;
    }
}
```

In the main method write:

```
private static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var test = new Test();
    var results = new List<int>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        results.Add(test.GetData(i));

    Task.WaitAll();
    Console.WriteLine(string.Join(",",results));
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

And now see results.

Finally, according to the description given, one of the correct implementation of your code is as follows:

```
public virtual Data GetData(Credential credential)
{
    Task<Data> inProgressDataTask = null;
    lock (_gettingDataTaskLock)
    {
        inProgressDataTask = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => GetDataInternal(credential));
        inProgressDataTask.ContinueWith((task) =>
        {
            lock (_gettingDataTaskLock)
            {
                //inProgressDataTask = null;
            }
        },
        TaskContinuationOptions.ExecuteSynchronously);
    }

    try
    {
        return inProgressDataTask.Result;
    }
    catch (AggregateException ex)
    {
        throw ex.InnerException;
    }
}
```