# How to use MemoryCache insted of Timer to trigger a method?

Tags: c#, multithreading, memorycache

The following method handle concurrent request by waiting the result of an already running operation.

Requests for data may come in simultaneously with same/different credentials. For each unique set of credentials there can be at most one `GetCurrentInternal` call in progress, with the result from that one call returned to all queued waiters when it is ready.

```
private readonly ConcurrentDictionary<Credentials, Lazy<Data>> _dataToCredentialMap =
        new ConcurrentDictionary<Credentials, Lazy<Data>>();

public virtual Data GetCurrent(Credentials credentials)
{
    if (credentials == null) { return GetCurrentInternal(null); }

    // It will only allow a single call to GetCurrentInternal, even if multiple threads query its Value property simultaneously.
    var lazyData = new Lazy<Data>(() => GetCurrentInternal(credentials));

    var data = _dataToCredentialMap.GetOrAdd(credentials, lazyData);
    return data.Value;
}
```

And I have added `timer` inside of this class in constructor. It's time-based invalidation policy where cache entries are auto-invalidated after a certain well-defined period of time.

```
_dataUpdateTimer = new Timer(UpdateData, null, TimeSpan.Zero, _dataUpdateInterval); // 1 min
```

Method that update data looks like the following:

```
private void UpdateData(object notUsed)
{
    try
    {
        foreach (var credential in _dataToCredentialMap.Keys)
        {
            var data = new Lazy<Data>(() => GetCurrent(credential));
            _dataToCredentialMap.AddOrUpdate(credential, data, (k, v) => data);
        }
     }
     catch (Exception ex)
     {
          _logger.WarnException(ex, "Failed to update agent metadata");
     }
}
```

I would like to use .Net `MemoryCache` class insted of my `ConcurrentDictionary` and `Timer`, to update my `Credential and Data` I think it will be more efficient.

I know how I can use `MemoryCache` instead of `ConcurrentDictionary`, but how can I call `UpdateData` each minute in constructor without a `Timer`?

Can you help me please how to do that?

Comment: Simply use the Set/AddOrGetExisting() overload that lets you pass a DateTimeOffset.  The DTO specifies when the item is evicted, same thing your timer does.

Comment: MemoryCache does not support making sure that only one value per key is created. You existing approach is fine.

Comment: @usr So I can rely on `ConcurrentDictionary` that only one thread can `GetOrAdd` some key/value, but if I change this line to MemoryCache.Default.AddOrGetExisting(...) it will be a bug?

Comment: @usr Even if previous call `var lazyData = new Lazy<Data>(() => GetCurrentInternal(credentials));` was thread safe?

Comment: Actually, I'm not sure what AddOrGetExisting guarantees. Probably you need to look at the documentation because I don't know for sure.

Comment: @usr Can you help me, please? I know that I can use `MemoryCache` instead of `ConcurrentDictionary`, but how can I call `UpdateData` each minute in constructor without a `Timer`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with MemoryCache without a Timer. Just set the CacheItemPolicy to AbsoluteExpiration:

```
MemoryCache memCache = MemoryCache.Default;
memCache.Add(<mykey>, <myvalue>,
          new CacheItemPolicy()
          {
            AbsoluteExpiration = DateTimeOffset.Now.Add(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(_expireminutes)),
            SlidingExpiration = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0)
          }
          );
```

Comment: My `_dataUpdateTimer` call `UpdateData` each minute. Inside `UpdateData` I update my dictionary. How you code can do the same thing just with `MemoryCache`?

Comment: You can react on the evict event of the cache item